# How do I determine what checkbuttons selected when created dynamically?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a custom file chooser in tkinter. I am creating a grid of checkbuttons representing files in a directory. Right now all i want to do is get a list of the file names a user chooses. As of now my code displays the gui nicely but when I try to determine what boxes the user checked it's not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Most likely in the way i'm setting the variable for the checkbutton. I know this would be easy for a python pro but i'm not a pro so any help would be greatly appreciated. See my code below. Apologies ahead of time for the huge amount of code but i'm not sure where i'm going wrong so i put it all in.

Mark

```
class scareGUI:

def __init__(self, master):

    self.selectedFileName = StringVar()

    #filter non video file types
    includes = ['*.mp4','*.py']
    includes = r'|'.join([fnmatch.translate(x) for x in includes])

    #master.attributes('-zoomed', True)

    self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
    self.frame_header.pack()
    ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text="TerrorForm ScareBox").grid(row=0, column = 0, rowspan = 2)

    self.frame_files = ttk.Frame(master)
    self.frame_files.pack()

    self.frame_footer = ttk.Frame(master)
    self.frame_footer.pack()


    #pull file names from file system
    for root, dirs, self.files in os.walk('./movies'):

        self.files = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in self.files]
        self.files = [f for f in self.files if re.match(includes, f)]

    #Determine number of rows in grid
    numfiles = len(self.files)

    dividesBy = False
    numRows = IntVar()
    numColumns = 4
    while (dividesBy == False):
        if(numfiles % numColumns == 0):
            numRows=int(numfiles/numColumns)
            dividesBy = True
        else:
            numfiles+=1

    #Print Check Boxes in Grid layout
    filmIcon = PhotoImage(file='tf_film_icon.gif')
    i=0
    self.checkedFiles=[None]*len(self.files)

    for r in range(numRows):
        for c in range(4):
            if (i<len(self.files)):
               self.checkedFiles[i] = IntVar()
               checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(self.frame_files, text=self.files[i], variable=self.checkedFiles[i])
               checkbutton.config(image = filmIcon,compound = TOP)
               checkbutton.image = filmIcon
               checkbutton.grid(row = r, column = c)
               i += 1

    def getChosenFiles(self):
        self.chosenFiles=[]
        for x in range(len(self.files)):
            if(self.checkedFiles[x].get()):
                self.chosenFiles.append(self.files[x])
        print (self.chosenFiles[0])
        return self.chosenFiles

def main():
   root = Tk()
  scaregui = scareGUI(root)
  root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It seems to be working for me after I fix the indentation problems. You're only _printing_ one value, but it seems to be setting `self.chosenFiles` to the proper number of files.

Comment: How are you telling it to print the files? when i call getChosenFiles() it says   object has no attribute. when i tell it to print chosenFiles[0] I get PY_VAR2

Comment: I can confirm - It works for me too. But I had different "problem" - I choose folder with subfolders and hundreds files and your class worked too long - I had to kill process.

Comment: Please make sure the code is formatted _exactly_ like it is in your file. As t is it won't run at all. My assumptions about how to fix it might not match your teality. We can't help if we can't see the actual code.

Comment: I can confirm my formatting was wrong. This solved my issue. Thank you.